# error app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug , Android Stuio ViewBinding

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.

> not a valid name: 570

Comment: show xml with code.